# make the specific number to become day of month

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

so i have this problem, i want to make specific number to become a day of month.
example: i had an output of label `5` now how to make it to become `05-12-2016` ? i just convert them into string like this

```
dim testing as string = ""
testing = Now.Year.ToString & Right("0" & Now.Month.ToString, 2) & Right("0" & "5" 2)
```

output :

```
2016-11-05
```

and if i use string, i cannot compare it with `date.Now`

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`DateTime` has [a constructor](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xcfzdy4x(v=vs.110).aspx) that takes the year, month and day of month as parameters that you can use to create an instance:

```
Dim dayOfMonth As String = "5"
Dim myDate = New Date(Date.Now.Year, Date.Now.Month, CInt(dayOfMonth))
```

You can use the [`ToString`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zdtaw1bw(v=vs.110).aspx) method to format the date however you need:

```
Dim format1 As String = myDate.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd")
Dim format2 As String = myDate.ToString("dd-MM-yyyy")
```